# Chain jQuery promises

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, eval, promise

I am trying to chain promises, not piping, just chaining.

For example, I have this method:

```
var execute = function(x){
   // this could be an AJAX call
   var d= $.Deferred();

    console.log('Begin ' + x);

    setTimeout(function(){
       console.log('End ' + x);            
       d.resolve();
    },500);

    return d;
};
```

And I want to execute this method a number of times, but one after the other. I have created a  method that does than using `eval`, but I am not quite happy with using `eval`:

```
var executeTimes = function(r){
    var s = '';
    for(var i=0;i<r;i++){
        s = s + 'execute('+i+')';
        if(i!==r-1)
        s = s + '.then(function(){';
    }

    for(var i=0;i<r-1;i++){
        s= s+'})';
    }

    eval(s);
}
```

The idea is that doing `executeTimes(3);` you get this output:

```
Begin 0 
End 0 
Begin 1 
End 1 
Begin 2 
End 2
```

I have created a live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/vtortola/Cfe5s/

What would be the best solution?

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recursion looks neat here: http://jsfiddle.net/Cfe5s/3/.

```
var executeTimes = function(r) {
  (function recurse(i) {
    execute(i).then(function() {
      if(i + 1 < r) {
        recurse(i + 1);
      }
    });
  })(0);
};
```

You start a function that runs `execute` with `0`, and when it's done you start over again (through recursion) but this time with `1`. Before recursing, you have to check whether or not to continue: only do so when the incremented value is still lower than `r`.

Comment: Wonderful. I did a small change to work with an array : http://jsfiddle.net/vtortola/ZaCp8/  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

My approach is similar to yours, but instead of concatenating strings, I nest function calls :P

```
var executeTimes = function(r){   
    // The last (inner-most) step does nothing. 
    // just in the case we pass r <= 0
    var f = function(){}; 

    for(;  r > 0 ; --r){
        // Create closure with call to execute( ... ).then( ... )
        f = (function(_f, _r){
            return function(){ execute(_r).then(_f); }; 
        })(f, r - 1);
    }
    return f;
}
```

It returns a function that behaves as you want. If you do this:

```
executeTimes​(3)()​​
```

This yields the same output as your example.
One can easily adapt this example to support any function and any last step (I'm assuming  the function `toExec` wants to receive the "number" of the call):

```
var executeTimes2 = function(toExec /*a function*/, 
                            steps /*a number*/, 
                            finalStep /*a function*/)
{   
    // The last (inner-most) step.
    // just in the case we pass r <= 0
    var f = finalStep? finalStep : function(){}; 

    for(;  steps > 0 ; --steps){
        // Create closure with call to execute( ... ).then( ... )
        f = (function(_f, _r){
            return function(){ toExec(_r).then(_f); }; 
        })(f, steps - 1);
    }
    return f;
}
```

So your function could be called 3 times like this:

```
executeTimes2(execute, 3)()
```

Comment: That is a great solution. Damn, I will have to get my javascript books again :D. Thanks a lot.